# how to select group by LEFT(t.field, 6) in HQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hql

Clean SQL syntax (MySQL) allows to select with "group by LEFT(...)"
Example:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` t  
WHERE t.field1 = 777 AND t.field2 = 0 
GROUP BY LEFT(t.field3, 6) 
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

But if I try to use HQL:

```
" select t  from TableEntity t " +
" where t.field1 = :field_1 and t.field2 = :field_2 " +
" group by LEFT(t.field3, 6) " +
" having COUNT(*) = :other_condition "
```

I got an exeption 
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: LEFT near line 1, column 12 [

Is it possible to use HQL in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you can do what you want, because MySQL extends the `group by` -- an extension not generally supported by other databases.  You can do something like this:

```
SELECT substring(t.field3, 1, 6), count(*) as cnt
FROM `table` t  
WHERE t.field1 = 777 AND t.field2 = 0 
GROUP BY substring(t.field3, 1, 6)
HAVING COUNT(*) = 4;
```

Note that the unaggregated columns in the `group by` are also in the `select`.